# Amazon S3 file uploaded; however, file could not be opened error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am uploading an image file into an Amazon S3 Bucket; however, when I download the file from the Amazon S3 bucket and try to open the file (jpeg) it returns an error stating "the file could not be opened."

[image]

I am sending a multipart request with the image file through AWS API Gateway as POST Method and after it runs lambda function to add the image gotten from the multipart request into the S3 Bucket. What may be the problem? Please Help Thank you!

**The Code Below is a lambda function that puts the image file into S3 Bucket.**

```
//* Upload Image into S3 Bucket
require("dotenv").config();
const region = process.env.BUCKET_REGION;
const accessKeyId = process.env.ACCESSKEYID;
const secretAccessKey = process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY;

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "ap-northeast-1" });

const moment = require("moment");
const busboy = require("busboy");
const getRawBody = require("raw-body");
const { gzipSync } = require("zlib");
const { Buffer } = require("buffer");

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const tableName = process.env.USERS_TABLE;
const bucketName = process.env.USERS_PROFILE_BUCKET;
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ region, accessKeyId, secretAccessKey });

const util = require("./util");

exports.handler = async (event, context) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const item = {};
    const filePromises = [];
    var contentType =
      event.headers["Content-Type"] || event.headers["content-type"];
    var bb = new busboy({ headers: { "content-type": contentType } });

    bb.on("file", function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      item.filename = filename;
      getRawBody(file).then((rawFile) => {
        item.data = gzipSync(rawFile);
      });
      file
        .on("data", (data) => {
          console.log("File [%s] got %d bytes", filename, data.length);
        })
        .on("end", () => console.log("File [%s] Finished", fieldname));
    })
      .on("finish", () => {
        console.log("Done parsing form!");
        resolve(item);
      })
      .on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Failed: ", err);
        return {
          statusCode: 500,
          headers: util.getResponseHeaders(),
          body: JSON.stringify({
            error: "Parsing Failed.",
          }),
        };
      });

    bb.end(event.body);
  }).then((res) => {
    try {
      var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: res.filename,
        Body: Buffer(res.data),
        ContentType: "image/jpeg",
      };
      s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("ERROR Uploading S3");
          console.log(err, data);
          throw err;
        }
      }).promise();
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: util.getResponseHeaders(),
        body: JSON.stringify(Buffer(res.data)),
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + err);
      return {
        statusCode: err.statusCode ? err.statusCode : 500,
        headers: util.getResponseHeaders(),
        body: JSON.stringify({
          error: err.name ? err.name : "Exception",
          message: err.message ? err.message : "Unknown Error",
        }),
      };
    }
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried using pre-signed URLs to immediately upload the image file to S3? It would probably circumvent this problem entirely. More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: @stijndepestel Haven't tried it but will look into it! Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to upload the same file and download and see if the issue persists and can you upload another file and see the behavior? This is just to make sure it is not a one time issue

Comment: Furthermore,  In multipart upload, there is less chance that upload fails. Did you observe any failure in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JavaScript (from within a Lambda function) to upload an image to an Amazon S3 bucket, try using the AWS SDK for JavaScript instead of posting to AWS API Gateway. For information on how to use the AWS SDK for JavaScript to place files in an Amazon S3 bucket, see [Uploading photos to Amazon S3 from a browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html).